# 'Request' is not defined-python 3

Tags: python

Global name 'Request' is not defined.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = ''

# sitekey retrieval
def get_sitekey():
    captcha_page = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36'
                    '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.28 Safari/537.36'})
    product_page = urlopen(captcha_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page, 'html.parser')
    sitekey = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'g-recaptcha'})['data-sitekey']
    print(sitekey)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_sitekey()
```

Comment: I imagine you want `requests.Request`

Comment: or `from requests import *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the Request object from within the request module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = ''

# sitekey retrieval
def get_sitekey():
    captcha_page = requests.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36'
                    '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.28 Safari/537.36'})
    product_page = urlopen(captcha_page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page, 'html.parser')
    sitekey = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'g-recaptcha'})['data-sitekey']
    print(sitekey)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_sitekey()
```